# How do I deal with my true love getting fat?

Tags: the-sims-3

So I've just installed Sims 3 and played a custom single Sim. Then I dated Jamie Jolina. While dating Jamie Jolina I've also dated Zelda Mae, also Blaire Sw0rd, and also Nancy Landgraab. I'm really planning to make Jamie Jolina my true love but then she got fat.

What made her fat and is there a way to make her slim again?

Comment: I don't play Sims from far away, but if I dont remember bad..., you can "marry her" or invite to live with you, and then you will be able to control her. So you can make her, run, go gym....etcc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make her lose weight by doing sports. You can influence her athleticism in several ways:

- If you have the Athletic trait, you can encourage her to be more athletic.
- Once you have gained enough points in the athletic skill, you can use exercise equipment to train her.

Comment: any idea why she got fat?

Comment: Sims get fat if the eat while their hunger meter is full. It could be that you've constantly performed actions with her that prompted her to eat (went on a date, served food and called her to table, etc.) Or it could be just a flunk of the game's autonomy AI.

Comment: hmmm, ok tnx. im sure that she didn't get fat because of me cause i haven't seen in a month while "flirting" with other blondies. do you think it might be because were not seeing each other? something most of us do in real life(maybe?)

Comment: I don't really know, I've seen NPC Sims get fat but I never bothered with the reasons